# Check for an entry in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
-----------------------
country | city | ids
-----------------------
India   Mumbai   1
India   Chennai  2
India   Kolkata  3
---------------------
USA    New York  2
USA    Utah      3
---------------------
```

I have given a sample from a table. From the table, I am trying to query all the countries without id 1. I wrote this(Country was not included in the Where condition since it needs to apply to all the countries of the table).

```
Select * from Countries
WHERE id<>1
```

I got this.

```
-----------------------
country | city | ids
-----------------------
India   Chennai  2
India   Kolkata  3
---------------------
USA    New York  2
USA    Utah      3
---------------------
```

But I need the output to contain only USA(which does not have id=1). Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: `WHERE country ='USA' AND ID != 1` give that a try :)

Comment: @connorg98 No. I do not want to specify the country. I want other other countries too if they don't have id=1. Any other way to do it?

Comment: i will edit my answer

Comment: Do you want to see all the country's without id 1?

Comment: @connorg98 Yes.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * from Countries WHERE country not in
(SELECT country from Countries WHERE id=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

use NOT EXISTS

```
Select * 
from   Countries c
where  not exists
       (
           select *
           from   Countries x
           where  x.country = c.country 
           and    x.id = 1
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to group by Country like below :

```
SELECT C.Country 
FROM City 
WHERE C.Country NOT IN
(SELECT country FROM City WHERE id=1)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/973da/8)

OR

```
SELECT 
  C.Country 
FROM 
   City C
GROUP BY C.Country
HAVING C.Country NOT IN
(
  SELECT Country FROM City WHERE Id =1
)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/973da/6)

Comment: I would like to know some comments for down voting